# How do I convert a G.726 ADPCM signal into a PCM signal?

Tags: c, audio, transcoding

I usually look to SoX or Window's built in audio libraries for this stuff, but it appears that neither have G.726 codecs.

So I have a sequence of bytes that I know are encoded as G.726 although the bit-rate and whether it is mu-law or A-law is not known at this time (experimentation will determine those parameters), and I need to decode them into a normal PCM signal.

So I downloaded the reference implementation from the ITU-T (ITU-T Recommendation G.191) but I'm kind of confused on how to use the `G726_decode` function. According to the documentation `inp_buf` and `out_buf` need to have the same length `smpno` and both buffers are 16-bit buffers. This seems to me like a step is missing; otherwise no compression is accomplished by using G.726. According to the Wikipedia page on [G.726](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G726) sample size depends on bit rate (from 2 to 5 bits). Am I supposed to do the decompression into samples myself? So if I assume maximum compression (2 bit samples) then each byte will produce 4 samples.

Example:

```
char b = /* read the code from input */
short inp[4], output[4];
inp[0] = b & 0x0003;
inp[1] = b & 0x000C >> 2;
inp[2] = (b & 0x0030) >> 4;
inp[3] = (b & 0x00C0) >> 6;
G726_state state;
memset(&state, 0, sizeof(G726_state));
G726_decode(inp, output, 4, "u", 2, 1, &state);
/* ouput now contains 4 PCM samples */
```

Or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like ffmpeg actually isn't able to do this, as I thought it surely would be able to... however, while I was googling I did find this [post to the ffmpeg mailing list](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2009-February/018843.html) which offers a solution.

Basically, there is a separate program called [g72x++](http://www.ps-auxw.de/g72x++.tar.bz2) which seems to be able to decode the audio to raw PCM for you.