# Retrieving audio captured by using camera’s microphone

Tags: c++, ip-camera

I'm programming C++ on Panasonic Camera. I sent a request to camera to retrieve audio captured by using camera’s microphone. Data is returned from camera has format as follows:

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" 
"Content-type: multipart/x-mixed-re place;boundary=--myboundary\r\n" 
"\r\n" 
"--myboundary\r\n" 
"x-Control=Idle\r\n" 
"x-Permission=Output:Enable;Input:Disable\r\n" 
"Content-Type: audio/g726-mixed\r\n" 
"Content-Length:  2048\r\n\r\n" 
(data) 
"\r\n"
```

(Data) is encoded in standard G.726. I need a C++ opensource library to decode G.726 and play back data after decoding. If someone knows then please show me.

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar has been asked before with a useful link

[How do I convert a G.726 ADPCM signal into a PCM signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508717/how-do-i-convert-a-g-726-adpcm-signal-into-a-pcm-signal)

The PCM signal can then be streamed to your output device, converted into another format or saved as a WAV file.